# Power Apps Form Development

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I want to develop a App in that many screens will be there in one of the screen one textbox will be there by clicking that box will navigate to another screen in that some options questions will be there and confirm button also there after answering the questions we need to click on confirm button it will navigate before screen where textbox is there , at that textbox one tick mark has to come .
Can anyone help me to develop this form ..

I was able to do for only one field ..

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box functionality in canvas apps for paginated forms.

At the end of your app's logic you will likely be using the Collect() or Patch() function to store the data entered somewhere. These require you to collect all inputs in a record.

You will have to create the screens one by one. I think the best approach would be to use a single variable during the entire process. You have 2 options:

1. Global variable: use the Set() function to create the variable and later Patch() to merge the new inputs with the results from previous screens.
2. Local variable: use the 3rd parameter of the Navigate() function to pass data between the screens.

Both approaches have their pros and cons.